# How to convert coordinates into local object coordinates in libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx

How to convert click coordinates (Gdx.input.getX (), Gdx.input.getY ()) to local object coordinates?
The screenToLocalCoordinates method does not work and does not convert coordinates.

current-some button

```
Vector2 mouseScreenPosition = new Vector2(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY());
 Vector2 mouseLocalPosition =current.screenToLocalCoordinates(mouseScreenPosition);
```

Comment: Could you provide an [MCVE](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2201/whats-a-minimum-complete-verifiable-example-mcve-and-how-do-i-provide-it)? It's hard to tell with the few details you've provided.

Comment: I added the code.When converting, the coordinates remain the same as they were originally

Comment: That's not an MCVE. Did you check [the source](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Actor.java) to help figure out what might be the issue?